# QuartzJobBean could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, quartz-scheduler, spring-transactions

When I run my SpringBootApplication and my QuartzJobBean triggers I get a HibernateSystemException that says `Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread`. I found a lot of similar problems (on SO) when I googled the Exception in the first place but none of the provided answers helped me out.

My ApplicationConfig looks like this. Here I set up my TransactionManager and the Datasource etc.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"de.xxx.yyy"}, exclude = HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

...

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        ...
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        ...
    }
}
```

Then I have another Config for Quartz - the QuartzSchedulerConfig. It configures the triggers, details and the scheduler

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class QuartzSchedulerConfig {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    QuartzTriggerProperties quartzTriggerProperties;

    @Autowired
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() throws ParseException, IOException {

        SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();

        AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
        jobFactory.setApplicationContext(context);
        ...
        factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        factory.setJobFactory(jobFactory);
        ...
        factory.setTriggers(collectorTrigger());
        return factory;
    }

    ...

    @Bean
    public Trigger collectorTrigger() throws ParseException {

        CronTriggerFactoryBean factoryBean = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setJobDetail(collectorJobDetail());
        factoryBean.setName("collectorTrigger");
        factoryBean.setCronExpression(quartzTriggerProperties.getCollectorTrigger())
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobDetail collectorJobDetail() {
        JobDetailFactoryBean factoryBean = new JobDetailFactoryBean();

        factoryBean.setJobClass(CollectorJob.class);
        factoryBean.setDurability(true);
        factoryBean.setApplicationContext(context);
        factoryBean.setName("collectorJob");
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }

    ...
}
```

Now when I start the Application the CollectorJob gets executed, processes its tasks and finally when it tries to save the `TransportVO` to the database it fails with this Exception:

```
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception. [See nested exception: 
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateSystemException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateSystemException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:296)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateExceptionTranslator.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateExceptionTranslator.java:68)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateExceptionTranslator.java:49)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
    at de.xxx.yyy.database.jobs.TransportDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$27fdef97.save(<generated>)
    at de.xxx.yyy.business.services.collector.CollectorService.saveEventForTransporter(CollectorService.java:314)
    at de.xxx.yyy.business.services.collector.CollectorService.downloadAndSaveArchiv(CollectorService.java:243)
    at de.xxx.yyy.business.services.collector.CollectorService.saveArchivesToDownload(CollectorService.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:724)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
    at de.xxx.yyy.business.services.collector.CollectorService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cdf948ab.saveArchivesToDownload(<generated>)
    at de.xxx.yyy.business.services.collector.CollectorJob.downloadArchives(CollectorJob.java:123)
    at de.xxx.yyy.business.services.collector.CollectorJob.doDownloadForAllServer(CollectorJob.java:87)
    at de.xxx.yyy.business.services.collector.CollectorJob.executeInternal(CollectorJob.java:73)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:75)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:719)
    at de.xxx.yyy.database.protocoll.QueryDSLSupport.getSession(QueryDSLSupport.java:35)
    at de.xxx.yyy.database.jobs.TransportDAO.save(TransportDAO.java:65)
    at de.xxx.yyy.database.jobs.TransportDAO$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d4e14826.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 22 more
```

The Service-Method that calls the save-Method of the `TransportDAO` is annotated with `@Transactional` and when the customer is using the application there is no problem with TransactionManagement an Session obtaining. So I'm guessing that my QuartzScheduler is somehow misconfigured. Any ideas what I have to change to make the QuartzJobs work?

Comment: Is your SpringBootApplication deployed in application server? Like IBM Websphere?